# Why does my PHP function prevent other code from working?

Tags: php

The issue my website is running into is that whenever I call the function **NoErrors();** all the validation preceding the function stops working, not only that but it does not appear to be adding data into the session. I've got various php validation for user inputs. As well as variables that are initialised at the start of the PHP document. This includes the counter variable **$totalErrors** as well as any **$_POST** data that may need to go into the session.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["cust"]["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
        $totalErrors++;
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["cust"]["email"]);
        // Check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
          $totalErrors++;
        }
      }
    }
```

This validation is used to sanitise user input. The function below is to check whether or not the **$totalErrors** variable has been incremented or not. Depending on whether or not the variable is incremented, it will redirect the user to the 'receipt' page or the current page so the user can correct their mistakes. Also, if it passes the check it's supposed to add the posted data into the **$_SESSION**. Most data here is just for testing purposes.

```
function NoErrors($totalErrors, $cleanName, $cleanMobile, $cleanEmail, $cleanCard, $cleanExpiry, $cleanCVV) {
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and $totalErrors == 0) {
  $_SESSION['cust']['name'] = $cleanName;
  $_SESSION['cust']['mobile'] = $cleanMobile;
  $_SESSION['cust']['email'] = $cleanEmail;
  $_SESSION['cust']['card'] = $cleanCard;
  $_SESSION['cust']['expiry'] = $cleanExpiry;
  $_SESSION['cust']['cvv'] = $cleanCVV;

header("Location: receipt.php");
} 
elseif ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and $totalErrors > 0) {
header("Location: index.php");
}
}

NoErrors($totalErrors, $cleanName, $cleanMobile, $cleanEmail, $cleanCard, $cleanExpiry, $cleanCVV);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `NoErrors()` uses lots of variables, which are undefined - `$totalErrors`, `$cleanName`, `$cleanMobile`, etc. If you turn on error reporting, you should see an error to that effect.

To fix this, you must pass in all the variables you're using as arguments to your function.

```
function NoErrors($totalErrors, $cleanName, $cleanMobile, $cleanEmail, $cleanCard, $cleanExpiry, $cleanCVV) {
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and $totalErrors == 0) {
        $_SESSION['cust']['name'] = $cleanName;
        $_SESSION['cust']['mobile'] = $cleanMobile;
        $_SESSION['cust']['email'] = $cleanEmail;
        $_SESSION['cust']['card'] = $cleanCard;
        $_SESSION['cust']['expiry'] = $cleanExpiry;
        $_SESSION['cust']['cvv'] = $cleanCVV;

        header("Location: index.php");
    } 
    elseif ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and $totalErrors > 0) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

NoErrors($totalErrors, $cleanName, $cleanMobile, $cleanEmail, $cleanCard, $cleanExpiry, $cleanCVV);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I had that originally but it was still producing the same result.

Comment: Actually, you're using lots of undefined variables. See my revised answer.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. I passed in all the variables but it still seems to ignore the **validation** preceding it and doesn't redirect to the next page. Could there be something wrong with the initalised variables?

Comment: Your code currently redirects to the same page, `index.php`, irrespective of whether there's an error or not. Should the first redirect be to `receipt.php` instead?

Comment: I've updated it in the question, thanks! Also it turns out it is the **elseif** statement in the function that's invalidating all other code. And it errors out when it's an else statement too. Any recommendations on how to correct that?

Comment: Else statements cannot have conditions.

Comment: What error do you get from the `elseif` statement? Post it in your question.